# Why does RegEx.test changes the result in subsequent calls?

Tags: javascript, regex

Why does the following go from `true` to `false`;

```
var r = /e/gi;
r.test('e'); // true
r.test('e'); // false
```

and then it continue switching `true`, `false`, `true`, `false` ......

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Its because of the `g` flag. It starts remembering the last index of the match and when you do `r.test` next time, it starts from that index. That is why it alternates between `true` and `false`. Try this

```
var r = /e/gi;
console.log(r.test('e'));
# true
console.log(r.lastIndex);
# 1
console.log(r.test('e'));
# false
console.log(r.lastIndex);
# 0
console.log(r.test('e'));
# true
console.log(r.lastIndex);
# 1
console.log(r.test('e'));
# false
```

Quoting MDN Documentation on [`RegExp.lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex#Description),

> The `lastIndex` is a read/write integer property of regular expressions that **specifies the index at which to start the next match**.
>   ...
>
> This property is set only if the regular expression used the "g" flag to indicate a global search. The following rules apply:
>
> 1. If `lastIndex` is greater than the length of the string, `test()` and `exec()` fail, then `lastIndex` is set to 0.
> 2. If `lastIndex` is equal to the length of the string and if the regular expression matches the empty string, then the regular expression matches input starting at `lastIndex`.
> 3. **If `lastIndex` is equal to the length of the string and if the regular expression does not match the empty string, then the regular expression mismatches input, and `lastIndex` is reset to 0.**
> 4. Otherwise, `lastIndex` is set to the next position following the most recent match.

The bold text above answers the behaviour you observed. After the first match, `e`, the `lastIndex` is set to `1`, to indicate the index from which the next match should be tried. According to the 3rd point seen above, since the `lastIndex` is equal to the length of the string and the regular expression doesn't match the empty string, it returns `false` and resets `lastIndex` to 0.

Comment: Great explanation! I felt like I was taking crazy pills.

Comment: So what's the use case here? When would that behavior be helpful?