# Regex, two ways, different results.

Tags: javascript, regex

Here goes two same ways to achive something. They both should do the same thing, but they don't.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/8vjctofs/

```
a1 = function(str) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]", "gi"), "");
}

a2 = function(str) {
    return str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/gi, "");
}

var string = "abc abc";
console.log(a1(string));
console.log(a2(string));
```

output:

```
abcabc
abc abc
```

Please, tell me why? Code is the same, except that first function creates regex, by new operator, second not.

Comment: this relates to a question I asked before, here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28910934/why-does-regex-test-changes-the-result-in-subsequent-calls

Comment: wait nvm I don't think so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `\\s` while using `RegExp` object:

```
a1 = function(str) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "gi"), "");
}
```

Otherwise `\s` is interpreted as literal `s` in `RegExp` object.

Comment: Woohoo! I will mark this post as an answer in next 9 minutes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
> console.log("[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]");
"[^a-zA-Z0-9s]"
```

String literals also use backslashes as escapes, and unrecognized sequences have their backslashes ignored. The escape never makes it to the `RegExp` constructor.

The correct way to do things, of course, is to always use regular expression literals. If you need a literal backslash in any string, though, it can be escaped too.

```
new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "gi")
```